# Populate PDF File from Database

Tags: ruby, pdf, ruby-on-rails-5, populate

I have a PDF file (Predesigned, I have no control over the design) which allows users to fill in some form fields in Adobe Reader and save the result. I want to automate the process of populating some of the fields (NOT ALL FIELDS), using the following steps:

1. Fetch data from database.
2. Open PDF template.
3. Populate form fields with data.
4. Save modified file to a separate location on disk.

**Restrictions:-**

- I have to do it in Ruby On Rails
- I can't change the file structure just open and populate the data on
  exact field like Name in Name field, DOB in DOB field, exact their
  positions like below:-

Help will be appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Fetch data from database.
> 2. Open PDF template.
> 3. Populate form fields with data.
> 4. Save modified file to a separate location on disk.

Step 1 is basic Ruby on Rails work: create one or multiple Models with each field in the form that you want to fill in, and then fill their table in the database (either with raw sql calls, csv import or manually entering them via the app scaffold views). Then read the models from the database.

Steps 2,3 and 4 cannot be done with ruby on rails alone, you need some extra library capable of manipulating pdf forms.

It seems like you could use the [pdf-forms gem](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) might fit the bill. I have personally not used it so I can't comment on how good it is. But it seems it is able to fill up forms, and for each model in your database, fill and save.